# Sitecore webapi No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI (404)

Tags: sxa, webapi

I would like to add some web api to my project but I am getting error that No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

What I could miss in settings or how I can see all sitecore routs and test it ?

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://my.local/rrapi/My/GetSometing'.","MessageDetail":"No
>   type was found that matches the controller named 'methodName'."}

It seems like I did all settings

MyController

```
[ServicesController]
    public class MyController : ServicesApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetSometing(string code) 
        {            
            return Ok("Done");
        }
    }
```

RegisterWebApiRoutes

```
 public class RegisterWebApiRoutes
    {
        public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes, args);
        }

        private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes, PipelineArgs args)
        {
            if (routes["MyName.WebApi.Default"] != null)
            {
                Log.Warn("Route 'MyName.WebApi.Default' has already been added. Ensure only a single route processor for MyName WebApi.", this);

                return;
            }

            routes.MapHttpRoute("MyName.WebApi.Default", "rrapi/{controller}/{action}/{code}", new
                {
                    code = RouteParameter.Optional
                }
            //,
            //    new
            //    {
            //        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("Get", "Post", "Delete")
            //    }
                );
            Log.Info("Route 'MyName.WebApi.Default' has registered.", this);
        }
    }
```

Configuration Patch

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>

    <api>
      <services>
        <configuration>
          <allowedControllers hint="list:AddController">
            <allowedController desc="MyController">MyNameSpace.MyController ,  MyAssmbly</allowedController>           
          </allowedControllers>
        </configuration>
      </services>
    </api>

    <pipelines>
      <initialize>
        <processor type="MyNameSpace.RegisterWebApiRoutes, MyAssmbly" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
      </initialize>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you try removing the `ServicesController` attribute from the controller? That could be conflicting with your regular routing.

Comment: @Kasaku I tried result is the same

Comment: Can you confirm your exact Sitecore version? Is SXA related to this at all, as you have tagged it?

Comment: @Kasaku my sitecore version is Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170614). about SXA I just wonder may be it could have any impediments

Answer (score 1):

You might try regist before different pipeline.

Here is an example as shown in below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <initialize>
      <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']"
type="LaubPlusCo.Examples.RegisterHttpRoutes, LaubPlusCo.Examples" />
    </initialize>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

More details you can find here https://laubplusco.net/implementing-webapi-service-using-servicesapicontroller-sitecore-8/

Comment: it is not works